90's film or show where people gain temporary powers
I believe this movie/TV show is from the 90s.  It was in colour, it might have been American.  I'd class it as a drama.  I cannot remember any of the actors.
This movie/show is about plane passengers who, while on a flight, black out or something. They all land and become what they were thinking of before they blacked out. Some of them end up with powers.
Scenes that I remember: (NOT IN ORDER)

Lady shows a man a tape of his wife, who is normally a mute and
wheelchair bound, saying how she loves him and appreciates what he
does for her.
a dead guy is autopsied, but cause of death is undetermined
They all end up losing their "powers" after some time

Some other things I remember from the plot:

One lady who is normally wheelchair bound and is mute becomes
'normal'
There's a guy that knows everything in the entire universe
The government keeps them locked up at the airport while they try
figure out what happened and eventually, it all goes back to normal
again

When things go back to normal, the lady becomes wheelchair bound again.
The end of the film/show is someone showing the husband of the wheelchair-bound wife a video of her saying how she loves him.

It is from a TV series called Miracles starring Skeet Ulrich. It's from season 1 episode 2 The Friendly Skies.


 part 1 of episode


 part 2 of episode
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0648898/?ref_=tt_eps_rhs_2
